# Where can I find the WKT standard or reference?

Tags: well-known-text, standards

I had a little confusion about the representation of a geometry as [well-known-text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) (WKT). I was searching for the WKT Specs to search for the exact representation, but I did not find the Standard. Is there a standards document or reference for WKT? where can I find it?

Comment: I guess _open_ doesn't necessarily mean _free_.  The only place I could find it is [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=53698). It appears a payment is required.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well known text for geometry is defined in [OGC 06-103r4](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfa) (amongst other places). Section 7 of that document provides the syntax. There is also a list of SQL functions relating to those in [Part 2 of the Simple Features spec](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfs) (also an OGC product).

The ISO documents are just a more expensive way to get much the same thing.

There are useful extensions such as the Extended WKT (EWKT) that is defined by PostGIS and supported by various other tools such as SpatiaLite, and provides the SRS, which you probably want.

*Update:* As pointed out in a comment, there is also WKT representation for Coordinate Reference Systems: [OGC 18-010r7](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/18-010r7/18-010r7.html). However these two WKT forms are using similar syntax to describe different things - one is for a geometry (e.g. a linestring), and the other for a CRS (e.g. for a geometric or temporal datum).

Comment: This has turned into a standard, on [this page](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/is) you may find *Geographic information — Well known text representation of coordinate reference systems* document.