# Difference between notations of WKT format: 'POINT()' and 'Point ()'

Tags: geometry, well-known-text

After reviewing this thread [Adding field with geometry in WKT format in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336841/adding-field-with-geometry-in-wkt-format-in-qgis) I started to wonder about the difference between the [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) notations: `'POINT(276547.16725324 5477265.87268898)'` and `'Point (276547.16725324 5477265.87268898)'` of the same vector geometry object. Is there any difference between them two?

The same applies also to `'LINESTRING()'` and `'LineString ()'`, `'POLYGON(())'` and `'Polygon (())'`.

I have seen some related threads:

- [What is the difference between ST_GEOMETRY and WKT?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153899/what-is-the-difference-between-st-geometry-and-wkt)
- [Where can I find the WKT standard or reference?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48269/where-can-i-find-the-wkt-standard-or-reference)
- [Difference between LINESTRING((x1 x2), (x3 x4), (x5 x6), (x7 x8)) and LineString([(x1,x2), (x3,x4), (x5,x6), (x7,x8)])](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401375/difference-between-linestringx1-x2-x3-x4-x5-x6-x7-x8-and-linestring)

Until now IMHO it seems to be more a software issue, rather than a dispute between Semantics and Syntax.

Comment: Technically, "Point" isn't a proper keyword, but it would be foolish as a developer to do case-sensitive comparison.

Comment: @Vince I think the specs explicitly declare the geometry tags to be case insensitive, and I believe they actually mention *PascalCase* for readability. Anyhow, there is no difference; WKT get's serialized by *geometry type specific* pattern matches with a set of tokens; simply put, the `<geometry_type>` tag preceeds a list of tokens (e.g. list of rings | list of coordinate pairs) that are enclosed in (multiple levels of) parenthesis. Whitespaces are only considered as part of a pattern when between a set of coordinates.

Comment: Well, there isn't just one WKT parser in all of creation, and plenty of room to debate whether `Point (0 1)` and `POINT (0.0 1.0)` and `MULTIPOINT ((0 1))` are all equivalent. But this seems more appropriate in Reddit than GIS SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of WKT was originally defined in the standard OpenGIS® Implementation Standard for Geographic
information - Simple feature access - Part 1: Common
architecture https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=13227. The current version of the standard is https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=25355 and that is used as reference below.

**EDIT**

Excerpt from 7.2.1 BNF Introduction (bolding added):

> The text representation of the instantiable Geometry Types implemented
> shall conform to this grammar. **Well known text is case insensitive.**
> Where human readability is important (as in the examples in this
> standard), an “upper camel-case” where each embedded word is
> capitalized, should be used

One can also try to interpret the BNF definition. In WKT geometry names point, linestring etc. are "names". "Name" is made of "letters", "letters" are made of "simple Latin Letters", which are made from a set of small case and upper case letters.

```
<name> ::= <letters>
<letters> ::= (<letter>)*
<letter> ::= <simple Latin letter>|<digit>|<special>
<simple Latin letter> ::= <simple Latin upper case letter>
|<simple Latin lower case letter>

<simple Latin lower case
letter> ::=
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m
|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z

<simple Latin upper case
letter> ::=
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M
|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z
```

Thus `Point` and `POINT` are both OK, and nothing wrong with  `poinT` either.

Comment: The `<name>` definition doesn't seem applicable to WKT, since while 'qweRtyAsdF' is a valid name, it isn't a valid geometry type. In 6.2.2 (p. 28) it states that `<Point Tagged Text> := POINT <Point Text>`, where `<Point Text> := EMPTY | ( <Point> )`, `<Point>` is `<x> <y>`, and `<x>` and `<y>` are " double precision literal" values. It *doesn't* state that "POINT" is `(P|p)(O|o)(I|i)(N|n)(T|t)`, so there's room for trouble. But I wouldn't reject `poinT` either.

Comment: Any help with interpreting BNF is welcome, but I think that "point" within `Point Text` refers to 0-dimensional geometrin object and not to any character string. But this sentence in 7.2.1 is rather easy to interpret:
`The text representation of the instantiable Geometry Types implemented shall conform to this grammar. Well
known text is case insensitive. Where human readability is important (as in the examples in this standard), an
“upper camel-case” where each embedded word is capitalized, should be used`

Comment: The examples in the linked document are all UPPERCASE in that section (6.2.3); it would have been nice if the case insensitivity of WKT was mentioned in 6.2, where WKT was defined, and included in the examples, as well.

Comment: @vince, I wrote only a link to the original OGC-SF standard to my answer but I was reading the current version of the standard myself. I added now also this link https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=25355. Table 6 in the current version has examples like `MultiLineString
((10 10, 20 20), (15 15, 30 15))`.

Comment: Okay, so the original standard and examples were all uppercase and the current specification, copyrighted 10+ years after I wrote my first case-insensitive parser, is now explicitly case-insensitive. So the real difference between `POINT` and `Point` is when the export function that generated the WKT was written.