# Converting LINESTRING wkt representation LINESTRING((a b),(c d)) to LineString[(a,b),(c,d)]

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, well-known-text

I know how to go from

```
line = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)])
```

to

```
LINESTRING ((0 0), (1 1), (2 2))
```

But not the other way around. How do I do this?

The reason I need to do this is that I want to be able to apply the following function to split my `LINESTRING` into its sides.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, LinearRing

def segments(curve):
    return list(map(LineString, zip(curve.coords[:-1], curve.coords[1:])))

line = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)])

line_segments = segments(line)
for segment in line_segments:
    print(segment)
```

and it cannot be applied to WKT representations of linestrings.

Comment: Check this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416048/difference-between-notations-of-wkt-format-point-and-point. And try this `from shapely.wkt import loads line2 = loads(wkt) print(line2)`

Comment: @kadir thanks! Changed.

Comment: This is a simple Python string formatting exercise, which might be better researched in [so].